# How do I transfer Dwarf Fortress saves from a PC to a Mac?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My friend introduced me to DF yesterday and I was wondering how to transfer the save files from my friends computer to my Mac as I don't have access to his computer everyday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The saves are located under the ~/data/save directory where Dwarf Fortress is installed. Grab the current/ and region[X]/ directories from your friend's computer and put them in your ~/data/save location-this will also contain the world.sav file (no rebuild necessary).

Note that if you already have a fortress on your installation, you may want to copy your current/ and region[x]/ folders to another directory (e.g. Backup fortresses) - I'd highly recommend this anyway because sometimes the game can crash while saving and corrupt your data.

Note: the [X] in  region[X] will be a number, depending on how many places your friend has rendered

Comment: If you are transferring the region[X] directory, it includes the generated world. There is no need to make a new world unless you want to start a new game.

Comment: Be careful doing this, I once did windows to linux and that didn't go very well at all.